# Aptana: WordPress Code Hinting

Tags: ide

Does anyone use [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for WordPress plugin development? Is there a way to set-up WP code hinting with Aptana?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, im and other users use Aptana always for WP Development and worls very fine. You must only include your install of WP for Dev or Stable to the project of your plugin, thats all. Now you can use all functions, vars, class ... inside your plugin of the referenced WP install.

If you start an new project; maybe an plugin, than add the externel directory or project in PHP Buildpath-tab of properties. Alternate you can change the properties via context menu, right mouse button on the project, and add the path or project in the PHP Buildpath.

**for Linux Users with Ubuntu Natty**

If you dont have the Command-Menu on your Linux install (if you use linux, than use this [hack](http://cometpeak.com/2011/05/menu-fix-for-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-11-04/).

**via Command Menu**

You can also use the command-menu for add an bundle, also WordPress is inside via Core from Aptana Studio 3. Klick *Commands* --> *Bundle Development* --> *Install Bundle* --> Klick *WordPress* and than *OK*; thats all.

After this you have all functions, etc.
[image]

Comment: That what i do but on eclipse ptd.

Comment: Don't forget to add a wordpress installation as external directory to the Buildpath. Only then the wp-code assist starts working. 
I just installed the bundle via Command menu and wondered why nothingn was working...

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Aptana but the top Google result said:

Aptana 3 click Command->Bundle Development->Install Bundle -> Select bundle to install->WordPress.

Comment: If you dont have the Command Menu on your install, its a current problem on Ubuntu Natty, than use this small hack: http://cometpeak.com/2011/05/menu-fix-for-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: Hi Wyck, Thank you for your comment. I didn't see that when I googled it. I should have chosen better search terms.